# Nested if else bash statement

Tags: bash, shell

Im trying to nest if else bash statements using `[[..]]` but I seem to be running into issues:

my line:

```
[[ $WRD == "tmp" ]] && tmpFlag=1 || [[ $someOtherVar == "test" ]] && tempFlag=2 || tempFlag=3
```

Basically, if WRD is `tmp`, then flag is 1, else if `$someOtherVar` is test, then the flag is 2 and if all else fails, then set the flag to 3.

But this level of nesting doesnt work.

- If I provide WRD as tmp, flag is set to 2. [WRONG]
- If I do not provide a WRD and `$someOtherVar` isn't `test`, then it is set to 3. [CORRECT].
- If I do not provide a WRD and `$someOtherVar` is `test`, then it is set to 3. [WRONG]

Comment: Think about operator precedence of && and ||. The tmpFlag=1 is treated as a statement and command and fails, so the || is executed.

Explain please why it would not be better to write this with if ... elsif .. else ... fi instead?

Comment: It would be better to write it with that.. but I was trying to see if it was possible to do it using the `[[...]]` functionality

Comment: It doesn't work the way you expect. If `WRD` is set to `tmp` then the statement `[[ $WRD == "tmp" ]] && tmpFlag=1 || [[ $someOtherVar == "test" ]]` succeeds (as a "whole"), so `tempflag=2` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike boolean operators in other languages, && and || have the same precedence.

The `tmpFlag=1` is treated as a statement and command and while it does not fail, there is nothing in bash that associates the || with the immediate previous term before a preceding &&, so the || is executed.

Here is a shorter snippet that makes that clear:

```
 tempFlag=1 ||echo nooooo && echo hello
```

Causes the echo hello to appear, because of `echo noooo` not because of the success of `tempFlag=1`.

Also consider this:

```
true && echo yes || echo no && echo yeeees || echo noooooo
```

give you both:

```
yes
yeeees
```

Explain please why it would not be better to write this with if ... elsif .. else ... fi instead? –

Also, why not use [ ]?

I would do it like this, much clearer:

```
if [ "$WRD" = "tmp" ] ; then
    tempFlag=1
elif [ "$someOtherVar" = "test" ] ; then
    tempFlag=2
else
    tempFlag=3
fi
```

PS, I also notice you have a typo, your first tmpFlag was supposed to be tempFlag. It doesn't change the behavior of course.

Another PS: using && and || instead of if .. elif .. fi is not really about the "[[ ]] functionality". You'd have the same problem if your were using the old test "[ ] functionality".

Comment: OK, as for the failure of space and tab, what I usually do is of course put quotes around $WRD, I forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

The `test && command1 || command2` syntax *does* work as expected but if
you append another command with `&&`, it breaks due to the operator precedence.
As a workaround, you can make compound commands as `command2` by surrounding
them with `{ ... }`.
Then would you please try the following:

```
[[ $WRD == "tmp" ]] && tmpFlag=1 || { [[ $someOtherVar == "test" ]] && tmpFlag=2 || tmpFlag=3; }
echo "$tmpFlag"
```

- if I provide `WRD` as `tmp`, flag is set to 1.
- if I do not provide a `WRD` and `$someOtherVar` is `test`, then flag is set to 2.
- if I do not provide a `WRD` and `$someOtherVar` isn't `test`, then flag is set to 3.

I'm not sure if it is readable than `if .. else ..` syntax but it works.
Note that you have a typo in the variable name `tmpFlag`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use braces for each of the "primary" options:

```
{ [[ $WRD == "tmp" ]] && tmpFlag=1 ; } || 
  { [[ $someOtherVar == "test" ]] && tempFlag=2; } || 
  tempFlag=3
```